# My c++ programs won't compile after I close the source then open it again

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc

I compile it, it runs and then I reopen it and doesn't work anymore.
This happens in devc++ 5.8.3 and codeblocks.

My code(the comments are default from the IDE):

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdlib>

    HPEN hPen;
    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT Ps;

    void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, HPEN pen){
        SelectObject(hDC,pen);
        MoveToEx(hDC,x1,y1,NULL);
        LineTo(hDC,x2,y2);
    }
    void Draw(int originx, int originy, float value,int handlength){
        DrawLine(originx, originy, (handlength*cos(value*180/3.14))+originx, (handlength*sin(value*180/3.14))+originy,hPen);
        DrawLine(originx, originy, -(handlength*cos(value*180/3.14))+originx, -(handlength*sin(value*180/3.14))+originy,hPen);
    }
    /* This is where all the input to the window goes to */
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        switch(Message) {

            /* Upon destruction, tell the main thread to stop */
            case WM_DESTROY: {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
            case WM_PAINT: {
                int r;
                int g;
                int b;
                hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
                for(int i=0;i<170;i=i+1){   
                r = rand() % 256;
                g = rand() % 256;
                b = rand() % 256;
                Sleep(10);
                hPen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 1, RGB(r, g, b));
                Draw(320,240,i,180);

                }       
                EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
                break;
            }
            /* All other messages (a lot of them) are processed using default procedures */
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /* The 'main' function of Win32 GUI programs: this is where execution starts */
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        WNDCLASSEX wc; /* A properties struct of our window */
        HWND hwnd; /* A 'HANDLE', hence the H, or a pointer to our window */
        MSG msg; /* A temporary location for all messages */

        /* zero out the struct and set the stuff we want to modify */
        memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
        wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; /* This is where we will send messages to */
        wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
        wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

        /* White, COLOR_WINDOW is just a #define for a system color, try Ctrl+Clicking it */
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
        wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* Load a standard icon */
        wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

        if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","Lines",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
            CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
            640, /* width */
            480, /* height */
            NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

        if(hwnd == NULL) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        /*
            This is the heart of our program where all input is processed and 
            sent to WndProc. Note that GetMessage blocks code flow until it receives something, so
            this loop will not produce unreasonably high CPU usage
        */
        while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { /* If no error is received... */
            TranslateMessage(&msg); /* Translate key codes to chars if present */
            DispatchMessage(&msg); /* Send it to WndProc */
        }

        return msg.wParam;
    }
```

Compiler log:

> - C++ Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\g++.exe
> - Command: g++.exe "C:\Users\Pall\Desktop\proj1\lines.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Pall\Desktop\proj1\lines.exe" -g3 -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc -g3
>     C:\Users\Pall\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRYW3Cy.o: In function `DrawLine(int, int, int, int, HPEN__*)':
>     C:/Users/Pall/Desktop/proj1/lines.cpp:12: undefined reference to`__imp_SelectObject'
>     C:/Users/Pall/Desktop/proj1/lines.cpp:13: undefined reference to `__imp_MoveToEx'
>     C:/Users/Pall/Desktop/proj1/lines.cpp:14: undefined reference to`__imp_LineTo'
>     C:\Users\Pall\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRYW3Cy.o: In function `WndProc(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned long long, long long)':
>     C:/Users/Pall/Desktop/proj1/lines.cpp:36: undefined reference to`__imp_CreatePen'
>     collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I tried reinstalling the IDE and googled the problem but nothing helped.

Comment: Did you try reading the errors?  Link is failing with undefined references.  For example, where is __imp_MoveToEx?

Comment: I have read it... MoveToEx(hDC,x1,y1,NULL); //---line13

Comment: That's where you call it.  Your program is compiling OK.  It fails because you aren't linking it with the library that contains the code.

Comment: Everything works fine before I close my IDE. [proof](http://tinypic.com/r/6oiu5x/8)

Comment: Everything worked fine before the Spanish Armada sailed, too.

Comment: Can you paste either a screenshot of your project's linker settings or the project file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is caused because you need to link the library libgdi32.a, if you are using the DevC++, click in Tools->Compiler Options, when open the window, check the box "Add these commands to the linker command line" and in the below textbox add the text:

```
-lgdi32
```

you form need to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thx it worked, but why does it open the console window?

Comment: @DireDuke By default the console is enabled, to disable, click in Tools->Compiler Options and go to Settings tabPage, select Linker and in the option "Do not create a console window" set to Yes. You can also hide the console calling the function FreeWindow()